# Disable Linking Step in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode

So, I have a setup a C++ XCode project which depends on quite a bit of .so files. Although the compilation phase succeeds on Xcode, the linking fails because it tries to link against the .so files that I think Xcode does not understand.

Hence, I have 2 questions:
- Is it possible to use .so files built on RHEL5_64 in XCode?
- If not, how can I disable the linking step in XCode so that the build phase succeeds with just compilation. (I can then periodically scp the code back to a Linux box and make sure it links and runs well)

Thanks!

Comment: Are there no corresponding dylibs (the OS X version of a .so) for your linking woes from the lib-project you're using? What is the project producing the .so's if you don't mind my asking?

Comment: No there arent there